# Building apache 2.4 RPM

Tags: httpd, rpm, apache-2.4

I'm trying to build up-to-date packages for httpd...

I would like to build Apache 2.4.4 (latest) as an RPM. so that i can install on multiple servers and not compile each time...

When i try to do 'rpmbuild -tb httpd.2.4.4.tar.bzz2' it says apr & apr-utils are dependencies.. I have already built apr as an RPM..

Does this mean that to build httpd rpm i will have to install apr & apr-utils rpm and then build httpd? Is there an alternative way

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the devel packages of `apr` & `apr-utils`:

```
yum install apr-devel apr-util-devel
```

There could still be problems building apache with it because depending on your distribution, the apr packages from your repo could be too old. In this case, you will have to get the apr sources for building. Check this HowTo:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/install-apache-2-on-centos-6/